# Java URLConnection Issues with Integers

Tags: java, url

I've been trying to get information from a webpage, specifically this site: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=%22pulmonary%20disease%2C%20chronic%20obstructive%22%5BMesh%5D (among other similar ones). I'm using the URL and URLConnection packages to do so. I'm trying to get a certain number from the webpage - on this page, I want the total number of articles (16428).

It says this near the top of the page: "Results: 1 to 20 of 16428" and when I look at the page source manually I can find this. However, when I try to use the java connection to obtain this number from the page source, for some reason the number it gets is "863399" instead of "16428".

Code:

```
    URL connection = new URL("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=%22pulmonary%20disease%2C%20chronic%20obstructive%22%5BMesh%5D");
    URLConnection yc = connection.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
    String html = "";
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) html += inputLine;
    in.close();


    int startMarker = html.indexOf("ncbi_resultcount");
    int endMarker = html.indexOf("ncbi_op");

    System.out.println(html.substring(startMarker, endMarker));
```

When I run this code, I get:

> ncbi_resultcount" content="863399" />

rather than:

> ncbi_resultcount" content="16428" />

Does anyone know why this is / how I can fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: what is nbci_resultcount? When I view source I find: <h2 class="result_count">Results: 1 to 20 of 16433</h2>. I think your indexOf is wrong, maybe consider using a regex?

Comment: Does it do the same thing if you set the user agent to something like a real browser? Are there any other differences in the returned HTML other than the search results that might give a clue as to why the search is returning different results?

Comment: @Kevin OP is saying the returned HTML is different in the Java code and browser.

Comment: I don't buy it, I just used curl and got the same thing as the browser.

Comment: When i say yc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla") I'm still getting the output: ncbi_resultcount" content="863492" /><meta name="

Comment: Pasted your code as-is, I'm getting `ncbi_resultcount" content="16433" /><meta name="`.

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce your problem and I have no idea why this is happening. Perhaps it's sniffing specific Java user agent versions. You'd then need to try to set the `User-Agent` header to something else to pretend as a "real" webbrowser.

```
yc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, I'd suggest to use a real HTML parser for this job, such as [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org). It's then as easy as:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=%22pulmonary%20disease%2C%20chronic%20obstructive%22%5BMesh%5D").get();
Element nbci_resultcount = document.select("meta[name=ncbi_resultcount]").first();
System.out.println(nbci_resultcount.attr("content")); // 16433
```

Comment: I second that. The server is probably returning a slightly different document when you pull it via URLConnection instead of a Browser. Have your Java program save the document to a file, then save another copy in your browser and compare them.

Comment: I tried in both Java 1.6.0_23 and 1.7.0. Same result with 16433. The OP's problem is unreproduceable for me.

Comment: When I use the Jsoup code, the output I get is still 863492 rather than 16433

Comment: What if you change the user agent header? Replace `.get()` by `.userAgent("Mozilla").get()`. Are you 100% sure that you're requesting the same URL as you've posted in your question? To track the HTTP traffic, you may find http://fiddler2.com useful.

Comment: Still getting the wrong result. I'm pretty certain that I'm using the same URL, seeing as how I copied and pasted the URL from my code into the question here. This is quite frustrating...

Comment: Something entirely crazy: try restarting your computer or using another computer. I'd however still be curious as to what Fiddler2 says about the HTTP request headers which are been sent.

Comment: All right, I'll try these out and post the results here. Thanks for all your help!